# Can I use const modifiers in IDL function definitions?

Tags: c++, idl

Can I use const modifiers in IDL function definitions that get parsed by MIDL?

e.g.

```
    HRESULT TestFunctionCall(
        [in,string] const char *szParameter);
```

Or will that result in breakages somewhere down the track?  It appears to make it through MIDL fine as far as the resulting _c.c and _s.c files go.

Comment: This is good question. Yes, admittedly the answer is straight forward, as it is covered in the spec for MIDL, but it is none-the-less something many people don't consider when writing their interfaces in MIDL, and it is nice to see brought to attention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `const` modifier is part of the [MIDL Language](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367088%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Therefore you can use it at your interface definition.

Comment: +1 Note: the list of things allowed to be declared `const` and the reasoning behind it is an interesting read.